# The best way to create Entity in public bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

What is the best way to use Entity in a public (tiers) bundle ?

- use trait
- use MappedSuperclass Doctrine
- another

The user of the bundle must be able to change the entity

For exemple: I have an MailerBundle with ModelMail entity but the App can't change the entity ModelMail (it is in vendor). How to fix it in MailerBundle ?

It is an good idea to have an entity in my tiers bundle or do I have to use an trait ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know the MakerBundle? https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html

Comment: In which version of symfony?

Comment: The tiers bundle must be compatible with SF 4.*. MakerBundle is the solution for app not a bundle.